# R - Checking if a string is a valid mathematical expression using non-standard evaluation

Tags: r, eval, lexical-scope, non-standard-evaluation

I would like to check if the strings below are valid mathematical expressions:

```
s1 = 'sin(x)'
s2 = 'sin(x*m)'
s3 = 'sin'
s4 = 'sin(xm)'
```

By 'valid', I mean the expression is a combination of

1. operators (must be used in conjunction with variables or constants)
2. variables `x` and/or `m`
3. constants.

By this definition `s1` and `s2` are valid while `s3` and `s4` are not.

To identify if a string is valid, I wrote a function `checkFxn` that first attempts to convert the string into a call or one of its parts. If successful, it then recurses through the call-tree and checks for the above conditions. If the conditions are satisfied, then the call is returned as-is. If not, an error is thrown.

```
checkFxn <- function(x) {

  lang <- str2lang(x)

  checkFxn2 <- function(y) {

    if(is.name(y)) {

      stopifnot(deparse(y) %in% c('x', 'm'))

    } else if(is.call(y)) {

      stopifnot(is.function(eval(y[[1]])) | is.primitive(eval(y[[1]])))

      lapply(y[-1], checkFxn2)

    } else {

      stopifnot(is.logical(y) | is.numeric(y) | is.complex(y))

    }

    return(y)

  }

  checkFxn2(lang)

}


#Applying checkFxn to s1-4
lapply(list(s1,s2,s3,s4), function(x) {try(checkFxn(x), silent = T)})
[[1]]
sin(x)

[[2]]
sin(x * m)

[[3]]
[1] "Error in checkFxn2(lang) : deparse(y) %in% c(\"x\", \"m\") is not TRUE\n"
attr(,"class")
[1] "try-error"
attr(,"condition")
<simpleError in checkFxn2(lang): deparse(y) %in% c("x", "m") is not TRUE>

[[4]]
[1] "Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : deparse(y) %in% c(\"x\", \"m\") is not TRUE\n"
attr(,"class")
[1] "try-error"
attr(,"condition")
<simpleError in FUN(X[[i]], ...): deparse(y) %in% c("x", "m") is not TRUE>
```

It seems to work as expected but I'm wary of my use of `eval` and was wondering if someone could suggest an alternative to using it? I know that it follows the usual lexical scoping rules, so I'm worried about it evaluating variables in the gobal environment - is there a way to restrict its scope? I've read the chapter on [non-standard evaluation](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Computing-on-the-language.html#scoping-issues) but I can't figure it out.

Also, is there a way to identify if a base function or primitive is a mathematical operator? I would like to use something more specific than `is.function` and `is.primitive`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Step 1:** Decide what constitutes a "mathematical operator". One option is to retrieve relevant groups from the [S4 generics](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/methods/html/S4groupGeneric.html). For example,

```
mathOps <- unlist(lapply( c("Arith","Compare","Math"), getGroupMembers ))
#  [1] "+"        "-"        "*"        "^"        "%%"       "%/%"     
#  [7] "/"        "=="       ">"        "<"        "!="       "<="      
# [13] ">="       "abs"      "sign"     "sqrt"     "ceiling"  "floor"   
# [19] "trunc"    "cummax"   "cummin"   "cumprod"  "cumsum"   "exp"     
# [25] "expm1"    "log"      "log10"    "log2"     "log1p"    "cos"     
# [31] "cosh"     "sin"      "sinh"     "tan"      "tanh"     "acos"    
# [37] "acosh"    "asin"     "asinh"    "atan"     "atanh"    "cospi"   
# [43] "sinpi"    "tanpi"    "gamma"    "lgamma"   "digamma"  "trigamma"
```

**Step 2:** Decompose your expressions into [abstract syntax trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree).

```
getAST <- function( ee ) 
    lapply( as.list(ee), function(x) `if`(is.call(x), getAST(x), x) )

# Example usage
getAST( quote(sin(x+5)) )
# [[1]]
# sin
# 
# [[2]]
# [[2]][[1]]
# `+`
# 
# [[2]][[2]]
# x
# 
# [[2]][[3]]
# [1] 5
```

**Step 3:** Traverse the ASTs based on your definition of "validity"

```
checkFxn <- function( ast, validOps )
{
  ## Terminal nodes of an AST will not be lists
  ## Wrap them into a list of length 1 to keep the recursion flow
  if( !is.list(ast) ) ast <- list(ast)

  ## Operators must be called with one or more arguments
  if( as.character(ast[[1]]) %in% validOps )
    return( `if`(length(ast) < 2, FALSE,
                 all(sapply(ast[-1], checkFxn, validOps))) )

  ## Variables x and m are OK
  if( identical(ast[[1]], quote(x)) || identical(ast[[1]], quote(m)) )
    return(TRUE)

  ## Constants are OK
  if( is.numeric(ast[[1]]) ) return(TRUE)

  ## Everything else is invalid
  FALSE
}
```

**Putting it all together**

```
exprs <- lapply( list(s1,s2,s3,s4), str2lang )   # Convert strings to expressions
asts <- lapply( exprs, getAST )                  # Build ASTs
sapply( asts, checkFxn, mathOps )                # Evaluate validity
# [1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

**Alternative to ASTs**

As pointed out by @Moody_Mudskipper, one can also use `all.names` to retrieve the list of symbols occurring inside an arbitrary expression. While this doesn't preserve the relative structure of those symbols, the names can be compared directly against `mathOps`.

Comment: Thank you so much for all your help and for taking the time to explain it so thoroughly Artem. I had been struggling with this so it means a lot to me.

Comment: I think once you have MathOps you can simply do : `test <- function(x) !length(setdiff(all.names(str2lang(x)), c(mathOps, "x", "m")))`

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper: Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately, this doesn't preserve the expression structure and will flag `s3 = 'sin'` as a valid mathematical expression, even though the OP defines it to be invalid.